# How to restructure very wide dataframes with dplyr using an index?

Tags: r, dplyr, reshape

I've read a number of posts on `gather` but I'm struggling to create a solution that would restructure a file with different widths into a long format.

My data are here:

```
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/bac3917/Cauldron/master/jazz.csv")
df2 <- read.csv(text = x)
```

In the above case, I have groups of 3 columns, each of which need to be stacked up.   I tried the following method but my values get spread into the wrong columns:

```
longJazz<- df2 %>% gather(key,
              value,
              X1:X69)
```

The resulting dataframe should have 782 rows and 3 columns (title, year and artist).

In another case, I have groups of 5 columns, so I'd like a solution that can be simply adapted. For instance, a function that takes as arguments a dataframe and the number of columns per group, would be handy.

Comment: Please provide a **minimal** example showing input and expected output.  The data should be self contained in the question and not read in from some external source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can remove the first column 'X', and then rename the columns until the last column 'id', by a sequence of 'Details', 'year', 'Description', then use `pivot_longer` from `tidyr` to reshape into 'long' format

```
library(stringr)
library(dplyr)
library(readr)
library(tidyr)
df2 <- df2[-1]
i1 <- as.integer(gl(ncol(df2)-1, 3, ncol(df2)-1))

names(df2)[1:69] <- str_c(c("Details", "year", "Description"), i1, sep="_") 


df2 %>% 
    mutate_at(vars(starts_with('year')), ~ as.integer(as.character(.))) %>%  
    pivot_longer(cols = -id, names_sep="_", names_to = c(".value", "group")) %>%
    select(-group)
# A tibble: 1,150 x 4
#      id Details                                                  year Description                                                                        
#   <int> <fct>                                                   <int> <fct>                                                                              
# 1     1 Sophisticated Lady / Tea For Two                         1933 Art Tatum                                                                          
# 2     1 The Genius Of Art Tatum, No. 21                          1955 Art Tatum                                                                          
# 3     1 The Tatum Group Masterpieces, Vol. 5                     1964 Art Tatum / Lionel Hampton / Harry Edison / Buddy Rich / Red Callender / Barney Ke…
# 4     1 Live Sessions 1940 / 1941                                1975 Art Tatum                                                                          
# 5     1 20th Century Piano Genius                                1986 Art Tatum                                                                          
# 6     1 Jazz Masters (100 Ans De Jazz)                           1998 Art Tatum                                                                          
# 7     1 The Art Tatum - Ben Webster Quartet                      2015 Art Tatum / Ben Webster                                                            
# 8     1 El Gran Tatum                                              NA Art Tatum                                                                          
# 9     1 Sweet Georgia Brown / Shiek Of Araby / Back O' Town Bl…  1945 Benny Goodman Quintet* / Esquire All Stars Featuring Louis Armstrong               
#10     1 The Immortal Live Sessions 1944/1947                     1975 Louis Armstrong                                                                    
# … with 1,140 more rows
```

Comment: thank you!  I saw your earlier post on this topic but couldn't get it to work.  What you just offered above is getting an error:     Error in get(nm, envir = fn, mode = "function") : 
  object 'pivot_longer' of mode 'function' was not found         I have the latest version of `dplyr` and `tidyr` installed.

Comment: @Ben I used `packageVersion('tidyr')#
[1] ‘1.0.0’`  What is your tidyr version?

Comment: @Ben `pivot_longer` is from `tidyr` >=1.0.0.  I am guessing you have `0.8.3` version

Comment: Yeah, I had just installed it but I'm still getting 0.8.3    I will try the development version?

Comment: @Ben  the `tidyr` 1.0.0 is in CRAN.  May be you can switch to a different repo?

Comment: @Ben Please check the CRAN version https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidyr/index.html   My R version is R 3.6.0

Comment: ok, got latest version of R to 3.6.1 and tidyr at 1.0.0, but now I get this error:   Error: Can't bind data because some arguments have the same name

Comment: @Ben I double checked the code by running again.  It is not giving any error or me though.  Have you changed the column names as in my code.  If so, the column names would be different.  Also, I removed the first column `df2 <- df2[-1]` before changing the column names

Comment: I found the error, which I may have added.  Basically, the number of names in i1 was not equal to the number of columns.  All good now.  THANKS!

Comment: FWIW the use of `mutate_all()` obscures a problem with `X68`, which contains both years (1998 * 2001) and artists ("Unknown")